# jquery - add a function to `ready()` or call if already `ready()`

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure how to do this, and the jquery docs were of little help.

At a certain point in my code, I need to run the function `foo()`

```
function foo(){ alert('foo()'); }
```

Usually, `foo()` will be called after the document is `ready` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){foo();})
```

But there is a chance that it might need to be called afterwards :

```
foo();
```

When I need to run foo, is there a way to either test if the document is `ready` or add it to the jquery `ready` promise ?

Wrapping `foo()` in the jquery `ready` promise won't run it if `ready()` has already run.

**UPDATE**

Based on KevinB's comment, I tried running a test on different jquery versions -- after loading.

```
$(document).ready(function(){alert('ok');});
```

I got the alert on every version.  Including the one I use ( 1.11.1 )

I tried wrapping tossing my code in a try/catch block; nothing.

$.ready shows the right function

It seems that something i installed broke the ready functionality. i'll go through all my plugins and try to figure out which.

Comment: *"Wrapping foo() in the jquery ready promise won't run it if ready() has already run."* that is absolutely false. http://jsfiddle.net/ALTG6/

Comment: @KevinB this seems to work on SO, but not on my local tests.  do you know if jquery changed recently? I'll update my version.

Comment: It has not changed in this regard since at least 1.2.6 (the earliest version i've used)

Comment: @KevinB thanks. i tested a few versions of jquery and everything works as you say (and what I originally expected) -- including my version.  it seems that something i installed broke jquery.  now I have to fix it.

If you change your comment to a question, I'll close/credit you.  It's the most correct response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wrapping foo() in the jquery ready promise won't run it if ready() has already run.

That is absolutely false. Adding another function to `$(document).ready` will immediately trigger the function if the document is already ready. You can use `$(document).ready` as many times as you want and whenever you want; it should *just work*.

http://jsfiddle.net/ALTG6/

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap it in a `.ready()` call.

If the document is not yet ready, then jQuery will queue the function to run later when the document is ready as expected.

If the document is already ready, then jQuery will run the function immediately.

So, you can just do:

```
$(document).ready(foo);
```

At any time.  `foo()` will get run either now if the document is already ready or later when the document is ready.

Working demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/BeEwT/

---

If, for some reason you're not comfortable just letting jQuery handle this for you, you could also do this:

```
function runWhenSafe(fn) {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        fn();
    } else {
        $(document).ready(fn);
    }
}

runWhenSafe(foo);
```

Though, I'd have to say that there's very little reason to write this extra code when `.ready()` pretty much already does this for you.

Comment: Or instead of verbose version you can simply write `$(foo);`.

Comment: @dfsq - I prefer to use `$(document).ready()` because I think the code is more readable and descriptive which is more important to me than using fewer characters.  In my hierarchy of priorities, readability and clarity comes before brevity.  You are welcome to have a different opinion.  But, once you've spent time working on lots of other people's code using libraries you don't know by heart, you will appreciate developers who make things readable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This is great and correct, but kevinb explicitly pointed out that what I was seeing was not was supposed to happen... which lead to me searching for bugs that broke javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If the rest of your code is wrapped in `ready()` then the the DOM is definitely ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   foo();

   // other code
   $otherElt.change(foo); // this is guaranteed to be called after ready event has fired
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with the following code:
`$(document).ready(foo});`,
`$(document).ready(function(){foo();});`,
`$(document).on('ready', foo);`, or
`$(document).on('ready', function() {foo();});`

Even if `'ready'` has been issued before, jQuery will take care and run your code afterwards.